# How to use Paypal express checkout on behalf of my clients?

Tags: c#, paypal

I would like to use Paypal Express Checkout on behalf of my clients.

For example, I would use their email address and setup a checkout page so the funds go into their Paypal account.

The documentation I can find talks about authentication by username & password.

```
// Sandbox API credentials for the API caller account
USER : // user id
PWD : // password
SIGNATURE : // signature
VERSION : // the release version of the API
```

But in my scenario I would only have their email adress?

I can't quite find any documentation regarding this, it always seems to be me as the client not on behalf of others?

Any ideas where to start?

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/

Comment: Each client would need to be registered with the API... What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID parameter in your SetExpressCheckout request to set where the money should go.  You can use your own API credentials and the user doesn't have to grant permissions or anything.

Of course, n in the parameter is the number of the payment in the request starting with 0.